# What's the name of the design pattern that makes a part of a class reusable.

Tags: objective-c, ios, design-patterns

I'm doing Objective-C for iOS, say I have several UIViewControllers.

Some of these view controllers will have a particular feature that I developed and I want to be able to reuse it easily.

The feature in question consists of two methods that use an instance variable of the UIViewController.

In Objective-C, it's similar to a category but that could be used theoretically with any kind of class.

I know this is not very clear but any help is appreciated.

Comment: please provide an example of ViewController features you've mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to implement your functionality as a decorator using the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: That would probably work but decorator is meant to be used dynamically and I really only need to 'decorate' the class at design time.

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass `UIViewController`, creating a custom `UIViewController` (say "sub1"). Then all of the `UIViewController`s that need that functionality can subclass `sub1`. This way you can easily reuse the code written once for `sub1` simply using [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Comment: That would work fine with the situation I described but then I couldn't have more than one 'package' of functionality.

Comment: Well, in that case you'll need more than one superclass to subclass. If a single class should need more than one 'package' you may consider using protocols to simulate multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

> ...The feature in question consists of two methods... that could be used theoretically with any kind of class.

well without knowing more details I'd say [Extract Class](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html) looks generally worth considering. For particular use cases, more specialized ones might be better fit than that ([Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), [Specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) etc etc etc)